# Why do people say flying FPV is harder than LOS?

Tags: first-person-view

I've heard people say that FPV is harder than LOS and I'm curious as to why- it's easier for me to stay oriented when I can see the aircraft's perspective, especially flying acro quads.

Comment: LOS is waaay harder, they're insane.

Comment: Never tried FPV. With LOS you have to understand control reversal and it is difficult to tell direction when the unit is far away. FPV however can make you lose situational awareness.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because flying FPV you have a limited view of the UAS position relative to yours and because your field of view is limited by the characteristics of the sensor (mainly the camera) that you have on board.
Moreover flying FPV you may get a misleading perception of the distance and a limited situational awareness on the obstacles surrounding your Aerial System that may lead in extreme cases to the loss of the UAS because you loose the radio coverage, you hit something or you run out of battery.
This is why in most of the Countries the rules dictates that you must fly LOS unless you have a proper clearece from the National Authority.
Hope this answers. All the best.